# Mobile broadband missing in 21.10 after upgrade

Tags: networking, 21.10, mobile-broadband

Upraded to Ubuntu 21.10 to fix Bluetooth issues I had. Unfortunately my mobile broadband connection stopped working right after the upgrade.

I don't have mobile broadband under network settings anymore and don't know how to resolve it. I have a built in SIM card slot on my Lenovo ThinkPad-T460s.